# X Exiting due to RUNTIME_ENABLE: Temporary Error: sudo crictl version: exit status 1 stdout: stderr: sudo: crictl: command not found

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, kubernetes, devops

I am facing this issue  while setting up minikube on amazon linux2
I am using minikube start --driver=none

Comment: Maybe installing `crictl` will help: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/cri-tools#install-crictl

Answer (score 2):

You need to install [cri-tool](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/cri-tools)

Follow these steps:

```
VERSION="v1.25.0"
wget https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/cri-tools/releases/download/$VERSION/crictl-$VERSION-linux-amd64.tar.gz
sudo tar zxvf crictl-$VERSION-linux-amd64.tar.gz -C /usr/local/bin
rm -f crictl-$VERSION-linux-amd64.tar.gz
```